# Changing choice value changes automatically to blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an issue with a SharePoint library and I cannot figure out what it is that's causing it.

When I click on a document, it opens and on the right you can press the small round button that opens the details pane. In that pane all your properties are shown and you can instantly change them.

In this when I have a choice value, and I change the value, the value immediately changes to blank. When I select the same value again, then the value does stay. When I change again, it goes blank first and when I select again, it does stay on that value (sometimes it takes more times).

Here's a gif that shows what happens to make it more clear:

[image]

This only happens in the detail pane. When I click 'Edit all' and change the value, it works perfectly from the first time.

Does someone has an idea what this could be? Or whether it's a bug?

Thanks very much,
Ski

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in SharePoint online, but I couldn't reproduce your problem.

[image]

I recommend you clear the browser cache or try it again in a different browser.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that too. And I noticed that sometimes it works, and many times it doesn't. I'm not sure if it might be related to radiobuttons?

Comment: This may also be the cause of network latency, and if this problem is always bothering you, I suggest you create the service request s to contact Office 365 support:   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/praveenkumar/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support

Comment: thanks. I'll do that!

Comment: Welcome. Please Upvote and accept it as an answer if you think the replies are helpful to you